# Google Chart Timeline: change bars shape and color selection

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

EDIT: this is the updated code, setFillStroke() change the color of the stroke:

```
        var observer = new MutationObserver(setBorderRadius);
        var observer2 = new MutationObserver(setFillStroke);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
          setBorderRadius();
          setFillStroke();
          observer.observe(container, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
          });
          observer2.observe(container, {
              childList: true,
              subtree: true
            });
        });

        function setBorderRadius() {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
            if (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) > 0) {
              rect.setAttribute('rx', 10);
              rect.setAttribute('ry', 10);
            };
          });
        };

        function setFillStroke() {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
                if (rect.getAttribute('stroke') == '#000000') {
                  rect.setAttribute('stroke', '#ffffff');
                };
              });
        };
```

With the same method I wrote a code for make round point the elements that have the same date of start and end (like new Date(2013, 01,01), new Date(2013, 01,01)):

```
function biggerPoints() {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
                if (rect.getAttribute('width') == '3') {
                  rect.setAttribute('width', '20');
                  rect.setAttribute('height', '20');
                  rect.setAttribute('rx', 20);
                  rect.setAttribute('ry', 20);
                };
              });
            };
```

---

I would like to round the edge of the rect that [Google Chart Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) create, and to change the stoke attribute color when an element is selected.
Since I can't find any option to do it I tryed with jQuery, but it's not working:

```
$('rect').attr('rx', '20');
$('rect').attr('ry', '20');
$('rect').attr('stoke', '#202020'); //just for test I'm trying to add the stroke attribute to all, but nothing appened
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use it! But the stroke attribute it changes every time someone click on the bars, I don't think I can change it when 'ready' event starts.

Comment: I did it, I updated my code with the solution. By the way your suggestion was crucial to find the solution, I would like to give you best answer (you have to copy your comment down below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify the chart elements when the `'ready'` event fires

however, the chart will revert back to the original style on any interactivity

use a `MutationObserver` to re-apply the custom style

see the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
  ]);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setBorderRadius);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setBorderRadius();
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function setBorderRadius() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
      if (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) > 0) {
        rect.setAttribute('rx', 20);
        rect.setAttribute('ry', 20);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```